# How to get the server URL back from the Session object in OpenCMIS?

Tags: alfresco, cmis, opencmis, apache-chemistry

I have a Session object.

I want to get back the server url from it.

IS it possible?

Comment: Probably it is, but still it would be nice if you state why you need this and how you connect to the server? Something like a server url can be easily retrieved elsewhere.

Comment: I have connected to the server using the session factory with the server url. I was just wondering if this was possible